Unable to Execute Event Handler Function using telethon
I'm developing a Telegram bot using the Telethon library. I've defined an event handler function to handle specific events in a Telegram channel. However, when a relevant event occurs, the event handler function doesn't seem to execute as expected.
Here all code:
import asyncio
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetFullChannelRequest
from config import api_id, api_hash, phone_number, welcome_message

session_name = 'new_session'

async def main():
client = TelegramClient(session_name, api_id, api_hash)
await client.start(phone_number)

    try:
        channel = await client(GetFullChannelRequest('yaebav1010'))
        channel_id = channel.full_chat.id
    
        @client.on(events.ChatAction(chats=channel_id))
        async def handler(event):
            print(f"Event received: {event}")
            if event.user_added or event.user_joined:
                try:
                    new_user = await event.get_user()
                    user_id = new_user.id
                    print(f"New user joined: {new_user.username or new_user.id}")
    
                    await client.send_message(user_id, welcome_message)
                    print(f"Message sent to {new_user.username or new_user.id}")
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Failed to send message to {new_user.username or new_user.id}: {e}")
    
        print('Bot started...')
        while True:
            try:
                await client.run_until_disconnected()
            except Exception as e:
                if "Disconnect" in str(e):
                    print("Disconnected. Reconnecting...")
                    await asyncio.sleep(5)  # pause for 5 seconds before attempting to reconnect
                    await client.connect()
                    await client.start(phone_number)
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error occurred: {e}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())

I verified that the event handler function is correctly defined and registered.
I ensured that the necessary event is triggered in the Telegram channel.
I checked for any errors or exceptions thrown during the execution of the event handler function, but there are no apparent issues.
I expect the event handler function to execute whenever the specified event occurs in the Telegram channel, allowing me to perform the desired actions in response to the event.

Telegram doesn't always send enough information for Telethon to construct a events.ChatAction. You can try using events.Raw instead.
